# Changing the XML structure generated by XmlSerializer in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have classes as follows

```
namespace Coverage {
    public class ClassInfo {
        public string ClassName;
        public int BlocksCovered;
        public int BlocksNotCovered;

        public ClassInfo() {}

        public ClassInfo(string ClassName, int BlocksCovered, int BlocksNotCovered) 
        {
            this.ClassName = ClassName;
            this.BlocksCovered = BlocksCovered;
            this.BlocksNotCovered = BlocksNotCovered;
        }
    }

    public class Module {
        public List<ClassInfo> ClassInfoList;
        public int BlocksCovered;
        public int BlocksNotCovered;
        public string moduleName;

        public Module()
        {
            ClassInfoList = new List<ClassInfo>();
            BlocksCovered = 0;
            BlocksNotCovered = 0;
            moduleName = "";
        }
```

With the following serializer code

```
XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Module));
// Create a new file stream to write the serialized object to a file
TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"test.xml");
SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, report);
WriteFileStream.Close();
```

I can get the following XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Module xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ClassInfoList>
    <ClassInfo>
      <ClassName>Fpga::TestMe</ClassName>
      <BlocksCovered>4</BlocksCovered>
      <BlocksNotCovered>8</BlocksNotCovered>
    </ClassInfo>
    <ClassInfo>
      <ClassName>Fpga::TestMe2</ClassName>
      <BlocksCovered>4</BlocksCovered>
      <BlocksNotCovered>8</BlocksNotCovered>
    </ClassInfo>
  </ClassInfoList>
  <BlocksCovered>8</BlocksCovered>
  <BlocksNotCovered>16</BlocksNotCovered>
  <moduleName>helloclass.exe</moduleName>
</Module>
```

- Q1 : How can I remove the `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://...` to have simple element `<Module>..</Module>`?
- Q2 : The XML element name is exactly the same as the class name or variable name. Can I replace it with my own?
- Q3 : Can I remove the outer `<ClassInfoList>`?

For example, how can I generate the XML as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Module>
  <Class>
      <ClassName>Fpga::TestMe</ClassName>
      <BlocksCovered>4</BlocksCovered>
      <BlocksNotCovered>8</BlocksNotCovered>
  </Class>
  <Class>
      <ClassName>Fpga::TestMe2</ClassName>
      <BlocksCovered>4</BlocksCovered>
      <BlocksNotCovered>8</BlocksNotCovered>
  </Class>
  <BlocksCovered>8</BlocksCovered>
  <BlocksNotCovered>16</BlocksNotCovered>
  <moduleName>helloclass.exe</moduleName>
</Module>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(btw, it doesn't tie to the question, but you should aim to avoid public fields, for lots of reasons covered in many stackoverflow questions)

Q3: Simply:

```
[XmlElement("Class")]
public List<ClassInfo> ClassInfoList;
```

Q2 re the top level name; you can use

```
[XmlRoot("somethingFun")]
public class Module { ... }
```

Q2 re member names:

```
[XmlElement("blocks")]
public int BlocksCovered;
```

(see also `[XmlAttribute(...)]`)

Q1 Removing the xsi etc can be done with `XmlSerializerNamespaces`:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "");
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Module));
ser.Serialize(destination, module, ns);
```