# XMLSerializer (C#) equivalent in Python?

Tags: c#, python, xmlserializer

I learned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013435/changing-the-xml-structure-generated-by-xmlserializer-in-c) that with XmlSerializer, one can generate XML based on the class structure with C#.

Does Python have similar/equivalent method to get XML file based on  its class structure?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can use pickling. You can also serialize basic types (lists, strings, etc.) to JSON or XML using the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Pyxer](http://coder.cl/products/pyxser/) that can be used to Serialize Objects to XML.

The (pyxer) Python XML Serialization and is a Python object to XML serializer and deserializer. In other words, it can convert a Python object into XML and also, convert that XML back into the original Python object. It uses a preorder traversal tree algorithm over the object tree and the XML tree.

Also Look here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/415983/