# Is XmlTextWriter The Best Way To Write Out Xml Data

Tags: c#, xml

I have a list of products I want to generate xml for currently all the products are held in a List<> object....

```
 List<Product> products= DataAccess.GetProducts();
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\ProductsToXml.xml", null);

            writer.WriteComment("Nick's Test Products To Xml.");

            writer.WriteStartElement("xml");

            writer.WriteStartElement("Product");
            writer.WriteStartElement("Name");
            writer.WriteString("Almonds");
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            //end for product
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            //end for xml
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.Close();
```

Now I was gonna use this skeleton and loop through all the products and add xml like the skeleton shows above. The thing is there is gonna be alot of writer.WriteStartElement instructions because my products have alot of data in them. I am not sure if this is the best way to create an xml file or does it even matter? Is this approach ok for what I am doing? Basically taking a product object that has a bunch of properties in it and creating xml out of it thats all the purpose of this code is for.

Would you guys do it different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)?

See also: [Introducing XML serialization @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=VS.100).aspx) and [Changing the XML structure generated by XmlSerializer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013435/changing-the-xml-structure-generated-by-xmlserializer-in-c).

Comment: Wow works great! Some of the properties of my product object are lists it even serializes the data in the properties lists to xml as well which is perfect.

Comment: Yes. None of that hand-crafted, time-wasted hootenanny.

Comment: One more question....What if I want to append a serialized list of "Category" data to the same xml file. So after its done serializing products, I have another List<Category> I wanna append that to the xml file. How could I do that?

Comment: You _could_ use one `TextWriter`, and `Serialize()` to it multiple times before closing the `TextWriter`. But, this could generate invalid XML, since valid XML must contain exactly one root element. To KISS, I'd say you're better off creating a wrapper object for everything you want to serialize - a `List<List<Category>>` would do.

Comment: @Matt, can you show me an example of what you mean by a wrapper? So I want a RootNode <NicksStuff>, then the List<Products>, then the List<Categories>, then close </NicksStuff>

Comment: It could be as simple as an object of type `NicksStuff` with two fields: a `List<Product>` and a `List<Category>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two options, one use a custom `XmlSerializer` for `List<Product>` or, more straightforward use Linq to XML to serialize your products:

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
products.Add(new Product() { Id =1, Name="Foo"});
products.Add(new Product() { Id =2, Name="Bar"});

XElement xDoc = new XElement("Products", products.Select(p => new XElement("Product", 
                                                         new XAttribute("id", p.Id), 
                                                         new XAttribute("name", p.Name))));
xDoc.Save(@"testOut.xml");
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
  <Product id="1" name="Foo" />
  <Product id="2" name="Bar" />
</Products>
```

**Edit:**

Composition is pretty easy in Linq to XML - so if I wanted an outer node of "Stuff" I can just prepend that node (and add a bracket at the end of course):

```
XElement xDoc = new XElement("Stuff", 
                             new XElement("Products", products.Select(p => new XElement("Product", 
                                                                           new XAttribute("id", p.Id), 
                                                                           new XAttribute("name", p.Name)))));
```

you can just duplicate this approach for your "Categories" list, just have `new XElement("Categories") ...` and so on.

Comment: Can you Add another RootNode to this example Like "Stuff" --> "Products" ---> "Product" also append to the xml file a List<Category>

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Item>));
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"items.xml");
serializer.Serialize(textWriter, items);
textWriter.Close();
```

which creates an .xml files with the root of 'arrayofitems'.

Answer (score 0):

How about making use of LINQ for serializing data? There are several articles on the net. Here is one. http://kiranpatils.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/generic-list-to-xml-using-linq/